# Get the order of list item in jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have done this http://jsbin.com/UBezOVA/1/edit.

When I click the submit button, i want to get the current order of the list item. But, it seems that 
`$("#sortable2").sortable("toArray")` does not show the current order of list (for example sortable2).
How to get the current order of a list.

Comment: by "current order" you mean an array of permutation [2,3,1,4,5] or a list of objects in order ?

Comment: Your selector is incorrect in the example.  You have `$('sortable1').sortable("toArray")` when you should have `$('#sortable2')` note the `#`.  Then your child `<li>` nodes have no `id` attributes, which are what get serialized. Correct the selector and add the ids. http://jsbin.com/UBezOVA/6/edit

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski   Thanks, i can set your answer as my accepted answer, if you write an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Part of your issue is a typographical error, omitting the `#` from the id in your jQuery selector. Otherwise, your usage of `.sortable("toArray")` is correct. (Note, I used `console.log()` there instead of `alert()` - watch the browser's console for better output)

```
function submit(){
   var idsInOrder = $("#sortable2").sortable("toArray");
   //-----------------^^^^
   console.log(idsInOrder);
}
```

However, [as documented](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) the `toArray()` method will use the `id` attribute of sortable items by default when serializing.  You will need to add a unique `id` attribute to each of the sortable items for this to work:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='i1'>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='i2'>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='i3'>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='i4'>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='i5'>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Put those two together and it will work as you expect: http://jsbin.com/UBezOVA/6/edit

Answer (score 10):

*gaurav* is on the right track, but as *purefusion* mentioned **"id attributes are always supposed to start with an alpha character"**

Accordingly,
The html valid approach is to add data attributes

```
const idsInOrder = $("#sortable2").sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'data-id'});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const idsInOrder = $("#sortable2").sortable('toArray', {
    attribute: 'data-id'
  });


  console.log(idsInOrder);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-id="1" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li data-id="2" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li data-id="4" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li data-id="5" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While the other upvoted answers work, I give my vote to this answer.  It shows the "toArray" along with optional attributes.

Comment: This approach is much better than using the `id`.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of *toArray* of *Soratble* [[link here]](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) clearly says that it `Serializes the sortable's item id's into an array of string.`

That means, you should use your sortable elements with an id for each one

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li id="4" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li id="5" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
```

And now your code `var idsInOrder = $("#sortable2").sortable('toArray');
alert(idsInOrder);` will definitely output an array.

Comment: It should probably be noted that id attributes are always supposed to start with an alpha character (hense i1, i2, etc as in Michael's example). That's not to say it won't work with just numeric id attributes, but it could lead to other problems potentially.

Comment: @purefusion in HTML5, numeric values in id fields are perfectly valid (Adding this comment as now almost everyone uses this version of html5).

Answer (score 1):

JS :

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
         connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
     }).disableSelection();
 });

 function submit(){
     var idsInOrder = [];
     $("ul#sortable1 li").each(function() { idsInOrder.push($(this).text()) });
     alert(idsInOrder.join('\n'));
 }
```

HTML :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
      #sortable1, #sortable2 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float:left; margin-right: 10px; }
      #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em;width: 120px; }
  </style>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
</body>
</html>
```

This should help to display the items in current order.

See final ourput here : http://jsbin.com/UBezOVA/21/edit

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  function submit(){
   var idsInOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
   alert(idsInOrder);
}
```

```html
 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='1'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='2'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='3'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='4'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='5'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='6'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='7'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
 <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
```