# How to get the order of a sortable list made with sortablejs?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

My code looks similar to this:

```js
new Sortable(sortablelist, {
                    animation: 150,
                    ghostClass: 'sortable-ghost'
                });
```

```css
.box {
        background-color: powderblue;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 25%;
        cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <center>
  
        <div id="sortablelist">
            <div class="box" id="Item 1">Item 1</div>
            <div class="box" id="Item 2">Item 2</div>
            <div class="box" id="Item 3">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im a beginner, hope you can help me. I feel like I already searched the hole web.
The order will continue to be saved in a database, but I am now a little experienced with PHP and think I can manage this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the order of list item in jquery sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702743/get-the-order-of-list-item-in-jquery-sortable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JQuery you can use `sortable.toArray()`.

```
$("#sortablelist").sortable.toArray("orderedIds");
```

This will put the IDs of all the items in the sortable into an array. So in your case it will return (if you haven't changed the order):

```
["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
```